# css3 div and anchor tag skew transform in different sides

Tags: css

I have a two div's and one anchor tag. Now the first div, I want to transform skew it only the right side of the div and the second div, I want to transform skew it only on the left side. The anchor tag, I want it to transform skew both left and right side (please refer to the image attach).

my html codes are:

```
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<a class="theanchor" href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a>
```

and my css codes are:

```
.box{
width: 900px;
height: 300px;
background: red;
}
.theanchor{
display: block;
padding: 8px 13px;
background: blue;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

and what i tried so far and my first source to figure things out is:

```
transform:skewX(10deg));
```

[image]

but nothing works, if anyone here could point me how to do it or how to make it, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The last shape should work with just `skew(10deg)` but I don't think a skew on only one side can be achieved with just `skew`.

Comment: yeah right, i think the choice i have is to use images instead to achieve what i want.

Comment: Nope, the shapes can be achieved without images also (although I personally would recommend images for complex shapes) but just not with `skew` alone. If you still wish to go down the CSS3 route, I can help with some samples.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a way around this, by skewing a container div, then creating a content div which unskews the content should give you the 3rd shape.

To create right angled versions, I gave the content div a background colour and offset it with position:relative and then left/right (depending on what side you want your right angle)

Example here:
https://codepen.io/zarocreative/pen/Jjopdmr

```
div.skewed-heading-container {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color:#0096aa;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px;
  padding:0 20px;
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg,0);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg,0);
  transform: skew(-20deg,0);
}

div.skewed-heading-content {
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  position:relative;
  right:-50px;
  background-color:#0096aa;
  padding:5px 30px;
}
```